# IIS 7.5 with SSO Auth or with a classic form with laravel

Tags: php, laravel, authentication, iis, ldap

I don't know anything about IIS, I've just started a project with IIS ans I already have problems. And I think that the problem comes from the IIS configuration.

So here is the case :

I have a website with a login form. Nothing is accessible while you haven't complete the login form.
Once it's done, I ask an LDAP to know if the user is known or not.
In order to develop the website, I set the IIS configuration Auth to "Anonymous Authentication".
Everything works fine.

Now that the website is done, I want to implement the last thing which is the SSO. So I've disabled the Anonymous Auth and now the Windows Authentication is enabled.

The problem is that I can't access my website anymore, it shows a Security Windows window. But even if I put my personnal account, it doesn't work.

If everything were working, I would have AUTH_USER and AUTH_PASSWORD in the $_SERVER array. But I've nothing.

Both login form and SSO should work. Because the website must be accessible on the company network and behind a VPN too.

Here are the specs of my project : 
- IIS 10, Windows 10 
- Laravel 5.4 
- adldap (https://github.com/Adldap2/Adldap2-Laravel) 
- IE 11 
- Windows Auth is enabled in my system (control panel, Windows Functionnalities)

Answer (score 0):

same issue as you ! 
I know it exists different type of windows auth, but I tried every configuration that I could find on the web.
Is it possible that the problem come directly from LDAP configuration ? 
or maybe iis config ? 
or directly something to activate on the computer env?